# New timseries during the time period in VAR

Tags: time-series, multivariate-analysis, vector-autoregression

I have six time series that are all within the topic of popular goods. Each of the series is created by different company and I would like to predict market share of the green one. I would like to use VAR model so the behavior of the other series is taken in the effect. Issue is, that red and blue series were launched after 2016, so until this point, their value is 0. It would be NA, but R does not like NAs in time series modeling)
While modeling, the R is not able to simply 'skip' the time until the launch and take in account only non-zero values. Of course, zeroes in the dataframe are effecting the prediction.

[image] 
Is there any adaptation or improvement of VAR model, that would take in account the launch of new product during the period of modeling?
Or is there any other approach for multivariate time series that is able work in this situation?

Comment: "R does not like NAs in time series modeling" is nonsense, that's entirely up to individual functions in specific packages to handle missing values or not. There are several that do, for example most functions that use models cast in state-space form will trivially handle NA's.

Comment: Chris, I have to admit that I forgot to mention that I'm using the vars package. But on the other hand, I'm talking about the VAR model, and from my search, it does not matter, what packages is used. VAR models are not able to handle launch of new TS during the modeling period unless implementing Markov chain to the model. I believe you comment is irrelevant to the question.

Comment: VAR can absolutely handle missing values because it is trivially in state-space form, the issue is that you have to use the Kalman filter to estimate the model and not equation-by-equation OLS, which is how `vars` does it. I don't have an answer to your question (I'm not sure which model would best handle your situation), I am just pointing out that you can in fact fit a VAR model with missing values, so you shouldn't dismiss it on that basis alone.